# Task not visible in Task Scheduler after using schtasks

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

```
schtasks /create /tn "Report monthly id 700" /tr "some path" /SC ONEVENT /EC Application /MO *[Application/EventID=700]
```

I get message

```
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "testReport monthly id 700" has successfully been created.
```

but I can't find it in Task Scheduler. Any suggestions?

Comment: when typing schtasks in the command line, I can see it

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting article about the visibility of Scheduled Tasks:
https://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-run-task-scheduler-task-as-limited-user/

With the mentioned code the Task becomes visible and even executable:

```
$scheduler = New-Object -ComObject "Schedule.Service"
$scheduler.Connect()
$task = $scheduler.GetFolder("").GetTask("")
$sec = $task.GetSecurityDescriptor(0xF)
$sec = $sec + '(A;;GRGX;;;AU)'
$task.SetSecurityDescriptor($sec, 0)
```

Maybe it will help someone else